# Stringy JSON causing too much storage to be taken up

Tags: javascript, json, web

So I am building a site where it suggests locations to visit in NYC. Though I want to save the data as JSON values in the local storage so that user can add their own and then I can add MongoDB. I use the JSON data to build the DOM of the site. But when I reload the page I lose storage space by the 15th or so reload, I know that its due to the strings being strung over and over i.e.

```
[[{"_name": "Stacks Pancake House & Smokehouse BBQ"
```

turn into :

```
"[[{\\\"_name\\\":\\\"Stacks Pancake House & Smo…on\\\
```

adding more backslashes for the previous back slashes taking up more and more room as I reload the pages till nothing loads due to the error of no more storage left. This also is an issue as the backslashes cause the site (DOM) to not to build properly as the JSON data has the issue of having extra and not needed the backslashes. I can't figure out what is causing this specifically.

GitHub: https://github.com/dogboy602k/NYC146/tree/jsonversion

Comment: How are you loading your JSON data? Are you sending back the data from the client to the database on each load?

Comment: How are you adding to this JSON data? You should `parse`, add an entry then `stringify` again and store.

Comment: @KevinPastor right now i have no DB so i am storing this in the local storage.  and whats suppose to happen is if its the first load of the page then some default data is loaded up, then put in JSON form and then then recalled to be built on

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir via setItem the json is in a list that is added to the local storage and then called to build on

Comment: How are you adding an entry to the JSON data? Are you just concatenating the strings?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I added additional comments on how the data should load/change/save.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did to solve this was have the part where the addition of a post (line 420) to be modified. I had removed the else section. so only on 1st load will there be a loading of lists. But when you add a "post" it up dates the list, clears the JSON list for that list, and then re adds the new list. So based on the inputs of season and price a var, seasonAdjust, is changed to know what list to remove and re add, to update. and with that it re adds the updated list.

```
var seasonAdjusted = "";
  if (season != null && price != null) {
    if (season == 'spring') {
      seasonAdjusted = "springlist";
      if (price == 'cheap') {
        springlist[0].push(newPost);
      } else if (price == 'fair') {
        springlist[1].push(newPost);
      } else if (price == 'expensive') {
        springlist[2].push(newPost);
      }
    } else if (season == 'summer') {
      seasonAdjusted = "summerlist";
      //more code
    } else if (season == 'fall') {
      seasonAdjusted = "falllist";
      //more code
    } else if (season == 'winter') {
      seasonAdjusted = "winterlist";
      //more code
    }
    if (seasonAdjusted === "springlist"){
      window.localStorage.removeItem(seasonAdjusted);
      localStorage.setItem('springlist', JSON.stringify(springlist));

    }else if (seasonAdjusted === "summerlist"){
      window.localStorage.removeItem(seasonAdjusted);
      localStorage.setItem('summerlist', JSON.stringify(summerlist));

    } else if (seasonAdjusted === "falllist"){
      window.localStorage.removeItem(seasonAdjusted);
      localStorage.setItem('falllist', JSON.stringify(falllist));

    } else if (seasonAdjusted === "winterlist"){
      window.localStorage.removeItem(seasonAdjusted);
      localStorage.setItem('winterlist', JSON.stringify(winterlist));

    }
```